# Convert assembly instructions to bytes in gdb

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64

Is there any way I can convert an assembly instruction such as

`cmp    %rdx,%rbp`

to bytes, but from text, not memory (so not by going to an address, printing it as an instruction and then printing it as bytes). Alternatively using some other tool than gdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called compiler explorer:
https://godbolt.org/

Using it you can choose the input and output of your code.
For example, for this case, you can insert the input as "Assembly" and in the output choose the flag of "compile to binary" to see for any instruction what is the relevant bytes for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works great, using binutils as the assembler (since that's what GCC and GDB use). NASM, which is selected by default, requires the flag "-f elf64".

Comment: @swaggg: NASM also doesn't support AT&T syntax such as `cmp %src, %dst`, only Intel syntax.  If you're using Intel syntax, you can use https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm or http://shell-storm.org/online/Online-Assembler-and-Disassembler/ (online front-ends to the capstone disassembler).

Comment: I find Godbolt extremely useful for compiler output, but binary assembler output is just as easy locally; compiler explorer's "binary" output is ugly.  You can just put your code in a file locally and run `gcc -c foo.s` && `objdump -drwC foo.o` on it.  (Wrap that up in a shell script for reuse if you want.)